# Ways to arrange student in descending order of marks

Tags: combinatorics

A class of 15 students is about to sit in a statistics examination. They will
subsequently be listed in descending order by reference to the marks
scored. Assume that there are no tied positions with two or more students
have the same mark . Find total number of possible outcomes .All student are different.

My attempt:
 Let students are a,b,c,d....o . 
If no student get same marks = 15!
If two student get.

But further it is getting complicated

I also try to think it like boxes there are 15 boxes but I failed to put right right restrictions .

Answer (score 1):

Not sure whether you're saying tied positions are disallowed, so I'll answer both.

If there are no tied positions, the answer is indeed $15!$.

If tied positions are allowed, you are looking for the number of weak orderings on a 15 element set, 
the 15th [Fubini number](https://oeis.org/A000670), $$230,283,190,977,853$$

Comment: I meant any two or more student can be on same position

Comment: Ok, then the fubini number is the answer.